# How to enable digital signing in PDF using Aspose and .NET

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature, signing, aspose

I have an Aspose license, I am able to fill a writable pdf from c# code. but after creating pdf from code, the control for digital signature in the pdf gets disabled. 
While this was enabled in the template and the template was digitally sign-able  but the output PDF is not. 
Any pointers ?

Comment: Was your original PDF Reader-enabled? (I.e. specially prepared by some Adobe software to allow additional operations in the Adobe Reader.) If it was, your changes have to be done as incremental updates to not damage this preparation, and not all of your changes may be allowed.

Comment: Thanks Mkl. I can try that.

Comment: I am a social media developer at Aspose and it seems that your issue is related to your specific template file. Share your code and template to show the issue or you can contact Aspose Support forum to post your template and our developers will help you out.